# Get x and y value when hovering on LinSeries React Vis

Tags: reactjs, react-vis, lineseries

Trying to get the x and y values at mouse over position.

```
<XYPlot
    xType="time"
    getX={ d => d[0] }
    getY={ d => d[1] }
    width={300}
    height={300}>
      <LineSeries
        color="orange"
        data={graphData}
        onSeriesMouseOver={(event)=> {
          console.log('val', event)
        }}
      />
      <XAxis />
      <YAxis />
  </XYPlot>
```

When i log the event i get {event: Class}.
The docs are not clear on how to get the value
[image]

I have tried event.target.value and event.currentTarget but they are undefined. Has anyone come across this issue before and have a solution or work around?

When i expand the event object i get the following

```
event: Class
altKey: (...)
bubbles: (...)
button: (...)
buttons: (...)
cancelable: (...)
clientX: (...)
clientY: (...)
ctrlKey: (...)
currentTarget: (...)
defaultPrevented: (...)
detail: (...)
dispatchConfig: null
eventPhase: (...)
getModifierState: (...)
isDefaultPrevented: (...)
isPropagationStopped: (...)
isTrusted: (...)
metaKey: (...)
movementX: (...)
movementY: (...)
nativeEvent: (...)
pageX: (...)
pageY: (...)
relatedTarget: (...)
screenX: (...)
screenY: (...)
shiftKey: (...)
target: (...)
timeStamp: (...)
type: (...)
view: (...)
_dispatchInstances: null
_dispatchListeners: null
_targetInst: null
preventDefault: (...)
stopPropagation: (...)
```

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(event)`?

Comment: the output is {event: Class}

Comment: could you expand that and give me a screenshot

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have added what is available to me on the event object to my original question.

Comment: expand again the `target` field

Comment: it's target: null when i expand and when i console log event.target i get undefined

Comment: try with `currentTarget` and `nativeEevent`

Comment: i didn't find a way to define an example in codesandbox in order to debug it

Comment: i get undefined for both.

Comment: could you provide an example in codesandbox